# Inspiron 9400 Laptop resolution shrinks when lid is closed

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, resolution

I have an Inspiron 9400 Laptop with an ATI Mobility Radeon X1400 Video Card. I've had both a 1440x900 pixel and 1920x1200 pixel display, and ever since I first hooked my computer up to my home TV (15 years old, via S-Cable), whenever I close the lid, the desktop resolution shrinks to 1024x768 pixels (whether the TV is connected or not. It's been at least a year since the computer and TV were connected, and it still resizes on every lid closure). It usually resets itself to whatever the desktop setting had been when I reopen the lid, but meanwhile it's resized all my open windows, and moved all my desktop icons around. I've dealt with it for a few years, now, but it's starting to not reset when I open the lid, again.

I have the most up-to-date driver that I can currently obtain (which came with the laptop in 2007, at this point, as I'm still running Windows XP Pro).

I saw a solution to check the registry, except that the "LidBehavior" registry entries don't appear to exist, or they don't show up in regedit.exe's "find" feature, at least.

I'm not sure what else to try, or how else to address this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Click Start > Control Panel.
Make sure the Control Panel is in Classic View.
Open the Power Options applet. In the Power Options Properties dialog box, click on the Advanced tab. In the Power Buttons frame are two boxes. Goto 'When I close the lid of my portable computer'. You'll have the options: 'Do nothing', 'Stand by' and 'Hibernate'. Select 'Do nothing'.
Click Apply. Click OK.


This setting shall work out.

Comment: It's been set to "Do nothing" for a couple years. It doesn't seem to matter what the power settings are set to, as soon as the lid closes enough to turn off, the screen size shrinks.